# How do I turn off the backlight but leave the LCD on?

Tags: linux, brightness, backlight

How do I set zero brightness on laptops that have a nonzero minimum brightness on the brightness control?

The solution should work regardless of X. I.e. it should also work in the virtual terminals.

Comment: Rewrite the driver?

Answer (score 3):

In the realm of laptops with Intel chipsets, there seems to be a division between the LVDS- and eDP-connected panels:

### eDP:

```
echo 4 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/bl_power
```

…should turn off the backlight.

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/bl_power
```

…[should turn it on again.](https://nikula.org/~jani/backlight/#index5h3)

### LVDS:

I have discovered that it is not possible to turn off the backlight on my Thinkpad X201 and X201 tablets via sysfs (bl_power does nothing; apparently, it is eDP-specific).

[This page](https://nikula.org/~jani/backlight/#index7h2) has a very lengthy description of the convoluted history of the backlight control in the linux kernel. TL;DR:

> i915 has supported bl_power for eDP panels (but not LVDS) starting
>   from v3.18.

**HOWEVER,** I have been able to make the backlight turn off by using a tool called `intel_backlight` from [intel-gpu-tools](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/intel-gpu-tools/). This requires root, since it apparently writes to a raw register.

```
intel_backlight 0
```

...turned the backlight off for me. Bumping it up with brightness adjustment controls re-enabled it here.

I also wrote a script that I hooked up to fire on a keyboard-generated ACPI event (in my case, fn+space, or `button/zoom`. If your system doesn't use that ACPI event, you need to use acpi_listen to find one that your system does have.

To trigger it, I made a file called `fnspace-backlight` in `/etc/acpi/events`:

```
# Wyatt Ward
# hook for magnify acpi event (fn+space)
# toggle LCD backlight on/off
event=button/zoom
action=/etc/acpi/actions/toggle-lcd-light.sh
```

I also made a file called `/etc/acpi/actions/toggle-lcd-light.sh`, marked as executable. This lets me toggle the backlight without changing the previously set brightness level, storing the temporary value in `/brightness`. Since ACPI events run actions as root, be careful.

```
#! /bin/bash
BRIGHTSAVEFILE="/brightness"
BRIGHTSYSFS="/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness"

# is the light on or off?
INTEL_BACKLIGHT="/usr/bin/intel_backlight"
light_state=$("$INTEL_BACKLIGHT" | sed 's/current backlight value: //g'|sed 's/%//g')
echo "light: ""$light_state"
if [ "$light_state" -eq 0 ]; then
  cat "$BRIGHTSAVEFILE" > "$BRIGHTSYSFS"
else
  # back up current brightness level
  cat "$BRIGHTSYSFS" > "$BRIGHTSAVEFILE"
  # turn off backlight
  "$INTEL_BACKLIGHT" 0
fi
```

Ad an additional fun note, you can control backlight with an incredible amount of granularity by modifying intel_backlight slightly. Changing it to read arguments as floating point numbers rather than integers, and to do floating point arithmetic, only requires tweaking a few lines of code and lets you make ridiculously precise brightness changes, including ones lower than the minimum you can get via sysfs.

Answer (score 2):

#### From X Windows

From X Windows you can use the application `xbacklight` to get and set the percent brightness for your screen.

#### Example

*current level*

```
$ xbacklight -get
100.000000
```

*set to 75%*

```
$ xbacklight -set 75
$ xbacklight -get
73.333333
```

*set back to 100%*

```
$ xbacklight -set 100
$ xbacklight -get
100.000000
```

#### From the console

To achieve something similar for a virtual terminal you'll likely need to interact with the ACPI settings via the `/sys` filesystem.

#### Example

*dims it*

```
$ echo "10" | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness 
10
```

*full brightness*

```
$ echo "15" | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness 
15
```

You'll have to play with this one, the range of brightnesses can be from 0-9 or 0-15, I believe it ultimately depends on your laptop.

#### None of this works?

If neither of these 2 options suites your needs take a look at the ArchLinux Wiki's topic titled: [Backlight](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight). That article contains every method I've ever seen employed to achieve this!

#### References

- [xbacklight man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xbacklight)
- [How can I change brightness through terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56155/how-can-i-change-brightness-through-terminal)

Comment: This is a useful way to get to minimum brightness instantly, but doesn't solve the problem because setting 0 (with either tool) just goes to minimum brightness, and they do not accept or respond to negative parameters.

Comment: …This is probably a restriction of the BIOS, and besides hacking the BIOS firmware or installing LibreBoot on my X60t (which I do intend to do), the only remaining possibility is to try to find a command to turn off the backlight directly. I looked at the ArchWiki article, but unfortunately `vbetool dpms off` also turns off the LCD. However, this happens a fraction of a second after the backlight and `vbetool dpms on` turns the LCD on a fraction of a second before the backlight, so maybe there's still a way to do this generically. Or maybe that delay is also a result of BIOS firmware code.

Comment: when I set 0 brightness, the screen is only dimmer, but still not turned off. I don't understand why.